# How to listen and check value of specific element in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have some simple app with spare parts for machinery.I have a shopping cart.I want to user add needed part to his shopping cart, but if it part is already in shopping cart it needs to change basic count to +1.

This is my firebase struct:
[image]

```
func addToFirebaseWatchList(object: ObjectFromPartsCatalogueList, user: FirebaseAuth.User){

    self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).updateChildValues(["userEmail": "\(user.email!)"])
    self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).child("order").child("\(object.objectFromPartsCatalogueListCode!)").updateChildValues(["count" : "1"])
}
```

How to check that the cart already contains a spare part with the same number and simply update the count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new value of a node depends on its existing value, you can either [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) or [perform an atomic increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments). Here I'd recommend an atomic increment, but that *does* mean you'll have to store the count as a numeric value (you currently have it as a string).

Once you store it as a numeric value, incrementing it is as easy as:

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).child("order")
  .child("\(object.objectFromPartsCatalogueListCode!)")
  .updateChildValues(["count" :ServerValue.increment(1) ])
```

*If the property doesn't exist yet, the above will set it to `1`. But if you already have a non-numeric value, it won't work. So as long as you are willing to wipe the existing string `count` values, it should be all good.*

I'd actually get rid of the `"count"` property in there, and just do:

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).child("order")
  .child("\(object.objectFromPartsCatalogueListCode!)")
  .setValue(ServerValue.increment(1))
```